# How do I use never remember history in Firefox effectively?

Tags: privacy, firefox

Under Firefox - Privacy and Security, I can change my history settings to never remember, remember, or use custom settings.

Right now, I have it set to remember history, under what circumstances is never remember effective? When should I use it?

I have a strong password for my user account, and no one other than me uses my computer.

From [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history):

> Private Browsing doesn't make you anonymous on the Internet. Your
>   Internet service provider, employer, or the sites themselves can still
>   gather information about pages you visit. Private Browsing also
>   doesn't protect you from keyloggers or spyware that may be installed
>   on your computer.

Comment: @TomK. - That's about sensitive information in the URL, I'm talking about browser history and files associated with it, stored on your PC. Firefox stores it in `places.sqlite`. I just wanted to know what advantages does setting your browser to private give you. According to the documentation it seems the only protection is on a local level.

Answer (score 0):

Remembering history is convenient, but history can also be detected in various ways by remote sites, allowing them to determine if you’ve been to *www.creepy.com* or *www.HIVinfo.org* .

Turning off remember history eliminates that, but all kinds of links and images are written to temporary disk cache that although deleted later is still recoverable. Strong passwords are irrelevant unless your drive is encrypted.

Private browsing mode keeps everything in memory and eliminates disk cache.

Anonymity is a whole different question.